# iOS 11, can't select the photo

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to remove the UIView, the UIView's "father" is a window object?

Now I face a problem. My app opens the phone album. If a device is iOS 10, I can select the photo.  Notice this, if a device is iOS11, I can't select a photo in this app.

I upload a video: https://youtu.be/t3cbU6MQs9w.

I found this UIView:
[image]

The view is someone else write into the project. Is this view make the bug?

I copy the same code to create a demo. The problem dismiss. The demo doesn't have the unknown view.

1. How to remove this view under the window?
2. Do you think what makes this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I remove the unknown view and this issue is solved.